# Firebase does not work in my reactjs code

Tags: reactjs

this code does not work.
what am I doing wrong.
I'm new help me.
Firebase V9 version
It's been three days and I still can't solve the problem.

how can i install firewase v8 on my react.

```
if (valid_data) {
      getUserAdmin();
    }

    async function getUserAdmin() {
      const db = getFirestore(initializeApp);
        const q = query(collection(db, "USERS"), where("email", "==", true));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        if(!querySnapshot.empty){
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth, this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then(res => {
          this.props.history.replace('/');
        }).catch(err=>{
          if(err.code === 'auth/wrong-password'){
          this.state.password_error="Incorrect password!"
        }
        this.setState({
          show_progress: false,
          });
      })
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to await getUserAdmin

Comment: If you know where I went wrong please correct me.